# Rails 4.2 run rake task after ActiveRecord load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rake

I have some data, which I want to pre-load in my add on booting. I've made an rake task and it works good. I tried to put code in `config/initializers` but it starts too early (I need all models to be loaded). `after_initialize` is not good too for me.  I place code example lower

```
require 'rake'
load File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'tasks', 'rights.rake')
Rake::Task['dev:create_rights'].invoke
```

So, where is good place to put this code? Of course I can put it in AR::Base or so on, but it is ugly.

Here is the task, if It will help.

```
namespace :dev do
  desc "Creation of the minimal rights"
  task :create_rights => :environment  do
    klasses = ActiveSupport::DescendantsTracker.descendants(AbstractModel)
    default_rights = RightsList.default_rights
    Role.includes(:rights).all.each do |role|
      klasses.reject{|klass| role.rights.pluck(:klass_name).include? klass.underscore  }.each do |klass|
        Right.create role: role, klass_name: klass.underscore, rights_per_class: default_rights
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Got dirty solution with adding in `config/application.rb`

```
config.after_initialize do
  require 'rake'
  load File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'tasks', 'rights.rake')
  Rails.application.eager_load!
  Rake::Task['dev:create_rights'].invoke
end
```

And I understand that it is still wrong way. Is here good way?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following all of your code. It appears that you're just seeding your database, or is there something more specific going on? http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data

Comment: Yes, it is seeding, but it should be run before project start (in production, of course I can use capistrano, in dev I can use sh, but it is ugly)

Comment: Can you not just use `rake db:setup` when you're starting off in dev? (I'll admit, it's possible you're way beyond me on this one, in which case I'd love to learn what you're doing...)

Comment: It is not a problem to run a task (actually, my task makes everything, what I need. And i need not rebuid db with `db:setup`). This task will add a record in db for all user roles about all classes, so if somebody add class- it will appear in db after this task. So it will be enough to run it only on sturtup. But default hooks does not work :(